# Check password when the return key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form below works, but **only** when the button is clicked.  Can someone please tell me how to submit this form and check the password with the script below when the enter key is pressed as well?

```js
function checkPassword() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'abc123') {
    location.href = "./yes";
  } else {
    location.href = "./no";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <form>

    <div class="user-box">
      <input type="password" id="password">
      <label>PASSWORD</label>
    </div>

    <div class="gradient-button-container">
      <input class="gradient-button" type="button" value="JOIN NOW" onclick="checkPassword()" />
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You change type of input to "submit"

```html
<input class="gradient-button" type="submit" value="JOIN NOW" onclick="checkPassword()" />
```

Moreover, remove `onClick` and add `onSubmit` event with `checkPassword` function on `form` tag

Comment: Thanks so much.  As it turns out, a return false was also necessary.  In case anyone comes across this thread and wants the working code, you just need to change the form tag above to <form onSubmit="checkPassword();return false"> and the submit tag  to <input class="gradient-button" type="submit" value="JOIN NOW"/>